# AngularJS: replacing templateURL with 404 page url when data is not loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This doesn't work of course, but should explain what I want to achieve:

In the factory "myapp.factory('gameService', function($http, $location) {" I load data from json feed
"return $http.jsonp('api/game/' + id + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')", if the data is not loaded change the templateURL, which was loaded in at first, to 404 page url instead.

```
var get_data = function (id) {
     return $http.jsonp('api/game/' + id + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
            .then(function(response) {
               //data loaded, do magic
            }, function(response) {
                //data not loaded
                templateUrl: 'views/page_not_found.html'; //<- how to inject this so it works?
            });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with ng-switch and ng-include

In the controller, when data is not loaded I added:

```
$scope.page_not_found = true;
```

And to the template I added:

```
<div ng-switch on="page_not_found">
   <div ng-if="page_not_found" ng-include="'views/page_not_found.html'"></div>
</div>
```

It doesn't really replace the templateURL, everything happens in one .html template. I hide the main content and import the 404 page with ng-include, this solution seems to be faster as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to make a state in route provider to 'page not found', like this:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
      })
      .when('/pageNotFound', {
        templateUrl: 'views/page_not_found.html'
      });
});
```

and in your function make this:

```
var get_data = function (id) {
    return $http.jsonp('api/game/' + id + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
        .then(function(response) {
           //data loaded, do magic
        }, function(response) {
            //data not loaded
            window.location = '/#/pageNotFound';
        });
```

};

Comment: This just creates infinite loop.

Comment: Infinite loop? Are you try it?